# How to insert into SQL database direct from Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I want to run this query from SQL in Excel:

```
INSERT INTO customer (name, age, gender)
    SELECT name = 'Frank', age = '19', gender = 'man'
```

The point is to insert into the `customer` table directly from Excel, without having to go through SQL.

I have tried the following statement in excel:

```
INSERT INTO customers (name, age, gender) 
VALUES('"&&"', '"&&"', '"&&"')
```

But I am not able to connect it to the database, and I have not been able to figure out how to do it in VBA.

Comment: *having to go through SQL* - what you're writing here ***IS*** SQL .....

Comment: Yes it is to show what I am trying to do in Excel. I want to be able to insert into an SQL database just by using Excel and VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Import and Export Wizard

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, connect to an instance of the SQL Server 2. Database Engine.
2. Expand Databases.
3. Right-click a database.
4. Point to Tasks.
5. Choose to Import Data or Export Data: